# wideimage - saveToFile() does not return true or false

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I am using wideimage script for image progressing.

It seem when I execute `$rounded->saveToFile('test.jpg')` to save file, it does not return true or false if the image has been saved.

```
var_dump($rounded->saveToFile('test.jpg'));
```

var_dump is showing `null` even if file has been saved.

So what is the solution to find out if the image has been saved?

Comment: Are you talking about http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the [source code](http://wideimage.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wideimage/trunk/lib/Image.php?revision=345&view=markup). It will throw [an exception](http://php.net/language.exceptions) (`WideImage_UnknownErrorWhileMappingException`) if the file cannot be saved.